# I localized my app to China, England, Dutch, etc. How do I go to local iTunes Store and check local feedback?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, itunes, feedback

recently I uploaded my app internationally. I found that the app is selling in China compared to other countries that I localized my app to.

So, I would like access to Chinese Apple App Store so that I can read their feed back if there is any. But I only have ID for North America, not China.

I tried http://www.apple.com.cn/itunes/     but this page is for downloading iTunes for Chinese users.

any ideas? many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the web interface, but you can switch the store from within iTunes. There is a little country flag all the way down in the right corner. Click on it to get to a page where you can choose the country whose store to show.

You can browse other countries' stores, you need the ID only to buy.

Comment: thanks. I was changing country flag in Safari not in iTunes. I got it now. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Especially for languages you don't speak fluently, the following can also be helpful and will display your app (or any other app) in your browser in the language of your choosing. Search your own app on the web, you'll find a link like:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/groink/id452227727

You can view the same information in other stores by changing the store identification part - "us" in the example link above for the United States store.

To see the Chinese page of your app, it would suffice to change "us" to "cn":

https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/groink/id452227727

A quick and easy way to find what you're looking for.